# Проблема с подключением драйвера ojdbc7

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Я скачал файл `ojdbc7.jar` с сайта `Oracle`. В командной строке прописал установку драйвера `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\Skorodielov\Downloads\ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7-12.1.0.2 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar`, установка прошла успешно. Запускаю IntelliJ IDEA в файле `pom.xml` в блоке зависимостей, `dependencies`, красным ничего не светится, но в `External Libraries` библиотека `Maven` не появилась. Подскажите в чём может быть дело и как это возможно исправить ?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что было причиной, но после того как ещё раз скачал файл `ojdbc7` с `Oracle` и выполнил установку драйвера, библиотека `Maven` добавилась. Может дело было в версии, версию в последний раз указал `12.1.0`

Comment: Иногда, после добавления зависимости в maven необходимо обновить его кнопкой "Reimport all maven project" во вкладке Maven projects.

Comment: ezhov_da, спасибо... буду знать, на будущее.